# read the error from Google API 403 error

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I am building an application that uses the google API for translation.

I can connect fine, all good. I need though to be able to read the contents of the 403 error in cURL:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

how can I configure cURL not to ignore the data that the google api spits out along with the 403 error header. It seems that the error header is causing cURL to totally ignore the jSON that the api is showing. I have searched all over but all I found is links to questions about how to connect - this is the issue I have, I want to be able to pull this error jSON into my PHP using cURL or file_get_contents. Any ideas?

It is importnant that I pull the error into PHP so the script can determine what to do, at the moment all its giving me is "not found". When I open the API call url in a browser, its pain to see the error.

---

update:

var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); gives:

```
array(20) { ["url"]=> string(48) "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2" ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(404) ["header_size"]=> int(360) ["request_size"]=> int(355) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.044256) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.001419) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.009028) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.034619) ["size_upload"]=> float(102) ["size_download"]=> float(9) ["speed_download"]=> float(203) ["speed_upload"]=> float(2304) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(102) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.044179) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) }
```

But this does not containe the JSON that I am trying to get hold of!

---

example PHP cURL routine:

```
$params = http_build_query($params_ar); // params contains all the connection auth and config.... its all good.

$api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

// find the 403 error JSON!!!!!

var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

echo "<hr>the url: ";

echo $api_url."?".$params;

echo "<hr>the body: ";

echo $body;

echo "<hr>";

var_dump(curl_error($ch));

echo "<hr>";

curl_close($ch);

// WHERE IS IT???????

exit;
```

Comment: what you get in curl_getinfo() ?

Comment: curl_getinfo(): 263 is not a valid cURL handle resource in

Comment: pass curl object like $ch as curl_getinfo($ch)

Comment: see updates question for response

Comment: try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

Comment: added that, now i get:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2012 15:06:15 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Transfer-Encoding: chunked Not Found

Comment: I have a suspicion that Google is returning a different result to my server and a json response to the browser...